# "ORA-01008: not all variables bound"

Tags: java, oracle

I used this code for simple displaying data of any randomly selected id but this error is occurring I saw a various post about this error but I didn't any result for my program, please suggest me what is a problem.
I am using following code

```
public class Demo {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:StudentInfo_Oracle","System","Aadi@123");

    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    String disq = "Select * from Sample where Id = ?";
    System.out.println("Enter id number which data want to display: ");
    int id = s.nextInt();
    PreparedStatement dis = con.prepareStatement(disq);
    dis.execute();
    ResultSet rs = dis.getResultSet();
    while (rs.next()) {
        System.out.println(rs.getInt(1));
        System.out.println(rs.getString(2));
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Well, you aren't binding the only variable you have, so.... seems pretty clear what is wrong?

Comment: you forgot to bind the value for id

Comment: you have to set parameter in `disq`.

Comment: there is no data is set on id because that value is set at the rum time by user.

Answer (score 0):

After PreparedStatement set value of `?`

```
PreparedStatement dis = con.prepareStatement(disq);
dis.setInt(1,id);
```

Comment: `id` is String or int?

Comment: sorry typing mistake